# Django form with emulated select elements

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I have a web application made with Django. One of the pages has a text field and a number of nested div's designed to emulate select elements.

I want to migrate this UI to Django forms as the current backend code is getting values straight from the GET object, thus bypassing any kind of security and validation the forms could provide.

What is the best way to migrate this UI to Django forms? What is the best strategy to have the divs emulating select elements in the forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows you to create custom fields for your forms.  In your case, I'd use the default django SelectField and provide it with a custom widget which builds the html in the way you describe.

[Custom form fields in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields)

[Custom field widgets in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances)